# JMeter - Remote into a Windows machine

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need to do the following via JMeter:

```
   1. MSTSC ---> Provide the IP address ---> Click on Connect.
   2. Provide the domain\username and password.
   3. Capture the time into a file (Start Time).
   4. Double click on a file.
   5. Wait until that (Desktop)application is loaded.
   6. Note the time in the same file (End Time).
   7. Subtract Start Time from End Time.
   8. Disconnect the remote session.
```

The output file should look like:

```
 Start_Time    End_Time   Load_Time
    
  10:00:02     10:00:07    5 secs 
  11:03:06     11:03:20    7 secs
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box JMeter doesn't support [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) protocol, there are no suitable [plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) either, so it's quite hard to implement.

You will either need to use a desktop automation tool like [Appium](https://www.blazemeter.com/university/appium-version-2-fundamentals) or automation library like [LDTP](https://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/) (both can be integrated with JMeter via [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)), but they will only give you possibility to automate an RDP client application.

If you want to get some RDP protocol metrics instead or as well or need the full control you should rather take a look at Java RDP client libraries like [jrdesktop](https://github.com/BachirBenyammi/jrdesktop) or [jrdp](https://github.com/marc-ashman/jrdp) or [Vinagre](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Archive/vinagre) and use the relevant functions or code from them in the aforementioned JSR223 Test Elements.